# Copying a CSV file to a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \COPY "Staging_Budget" FROM 'C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop\RD - F...
        ^
    ********** Error **********
```

when I try to execute this simple command:

```
\COPY "Staging_Budget" FROM 'C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop\RD - Facilities Management (001321).csv';
```

Can anyone tell me why that is?

Also, can anyone tell me why none of the examples online have the drive (C:) or the file type (.csv) listed in the filepath like I do?

Postgres version is 9.5 and my OS is Windows 7.

Thank you!

UPDATED:

I'm trying to run this statement instead:

```
COPY "Staging_Budget" FROM STDIN 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\csv\RD - Facilities Management (001321).csv';
```

I read [here](http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/10-intermediate-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/39-how-to-import-or-export-a-csv-file-using-postgresql-copy-to-and-copy-from-queries.html) that I needed to move the CSV file to the postgres CSV file directory.  I didn't have one, so I created it in the filepath in the statement above.  Now I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\csv\RD - Facilities Management (001321).csv'"
LINE 1: COPY "Staging_Budget" FROM STDIN 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Pos...
                                         ^
```

I don't understand why postgres doesn't like the apostrophe when it's given in every example I've found online and in the reference guide.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can *either* `COPY "Staging_Budget" FROM STDIN` *or* `COPY "Staging_Budget" FROM 'C:\etc'`, but not both. Since you're on Windows, you can ignore everything people are saying about `cat`. You don't want to copy from `STDIN`, you want to copy from a file.

Also `\copy` and `COPY` are not the same thing. In your case it looks like you want `COPY` (no backslash), which is the source of your original error.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Paul.  Also, do I have to have the CSV file in the postgres filepath?  The statement wouldn't work when the file was on my desktop, but when I created a CSV folder under the filepath, C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.5\data, it worked.

Comment: As long as it's somewhere Postgres has read permission, it should be okay. Of course you should provide the full path regardless of where you put it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can only use 'COPY .. FROM' by referencing an external file whenever you're in the server. I mean, the file must be accessible to the postmaster instance.

One technique I always apply in Linux is 'COPY .. FROM STDIN', by issuing a cat before psql.

Take a look at the reference guide:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: The Postgres database is on my computer, so the server is localhost.  So, the database should be able to reference any file on my computer, right?  I also tried COPY "Staging_Budget" FROM STDIN 'C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop\RD - Facilities Management (001321).csv'; and got a syntax error at the 'H:.  Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: The database process (postmaster) should be able to access that given file, that is, postgres user (in which PostgreSQL service is running) might have read permissions to the file.

Comment: For instance, in Linux we could issue: $ cat file.csv | psql -c 'COPY table FROM STDIN'. In Windows it is similar, so you could execute: > type file.csv | psql.exe -c 'COPY table FROM STDIN'

Comment: Maybe you're answering my question and I don't realize it.  If that's the case, I'm sorry, but I'm getting confused because I don't know what "cat" is.  I don't see it referenced in the reference guide and a google search doesn't return anything.  I've updated my question with what is hopefully a simpler question.  Can you take a look and let me know why postgres doesn't like that leading apostrophe before the file path?  At this point, I have no idea why it won't take it - it's in every example in the reference guide for the COPY statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this statement to work:

```
COPY "Staging_Budget" FROM 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\csv\RD - Facilities Management (001321).csv' (DELIMITER ',');
```

I guess postgres had a problem with the apostrophe used with STDIN?  Also, having the CSV file in a folder called CSV within the Data folder was needed.  Lastly, I needed to make sure that "(DELIMITER ',')" was at the end of the statement - even though the reference guide says that a ',' is the default when using CSV files...I'm not sure why I had to explicitly state it as the delimiter.